# Tkz-fct can't run in another drive (Windows User)

Tags: miktex, windows, tkz-fct

I try to run tkz-fct in drive D with location 
D:\latexrun but it can not work. Then I notice that package only run well in drive C as my Miktex location in **C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9** and in **C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX** .

In drive D the message show :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \tkzSetUpColors
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \tkzAxeY
!  Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \tkzDefPoint
Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@reserved@c ->\tkzActivOff
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@code.
```

This is sample I got from    [author's site](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/base/index.html) which is run well in drive C but not in drive D.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
 \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,tkz-fct}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon}
\tkzSetUpColors[background=fondpaille,text=Maroon]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=2];
\tkzAxeX
\tkzAxeY
\tkzGrid(0,0)(3,2)
\tkzFct[color  = red, domain = 1./3:3]{0.125*(3*\x-1)+0.375*(3*\x-1)/(\x*\x)}
\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](2) 
\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](3)
\tkzDrawTangentLine[color = blue,line width = .8pt](1) 
\tkzFct[color   = green, domain  =  1./3:3]{0.125*(3*x-1)}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=8,fill=orange] 
\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](3) 
\tkzDefPointByFct[draw](1/3) 
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){f}
\tkzDrawPoint(f)
\tkzText[draw,fill = red!20,text=red!50!black](1,1.5)%
{$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{8}(3x-1)+\dfrac{3}{8}\left(\dfrac{3x-1}{x^2}\right)$}
\tkzText[draw,fill = green!20,text=green!50!black](2,0.4){$g(x) = \dfrac{3x-1}{8}$}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have no problem calling gnuplot or another packages in drive D previously. I use Windows Vista Japanese Version SP2. Please help what should I do to make tkz-fct can run in another drive.

Comment: I'm the author of tkz-fct and you example works fine for me. I think that you have a problem with your installation. I'm not an expert with Windows but if `\tkzSetUpColors` is undefined then I can say that the package tkz-fct is not found. Do you install tkz-fct with Miktex or do you install the package without MikTex ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes I install tkz-fct using Miktex Package Manager (Admin), that is why it run well using drive c:\

Comment: @HarishKumar you are right, when I try to use drive E:\, it works.. I am confuse, what wrong with my drive D . Do you have any idea?

Comment: @HarishKumar . I notice only that folder in drive D:\ has problem. found that i mistakenly put another ***.tex which is make wrong output of tkz-fct. Please use your comment as answer, I accept your answer. Nothing is wrong with tkz-fct

Comment: I suspect you did not correctly made `tkz-fct` known to MiKTeX, see therefore [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483) and after this [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063).